# Kinect Camera with OpenCV - Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, kinect

I am using OpenCV and OpenNI with Kinect Camera for image processing project. I found this code from [here](http://seevisionc.blogspot.com/2013/12/opencvkinect-acquiring-kinect-data.html?showComment=1455755529828) to get video streams from the Kinect sensor. It has 4 options for the user to select which mode for acquiring data streams from Kinect. When I choose one, it gives me an error that says "Vector subscript out of range". I believe the error occurred on line `returnVec.push_back(m_depthImage);`  I specified on the following function.

```
cv::vector<cv::Mat> OpenCVKinect::getData()
{
    cv::vector<cv::Mat> returnVec;
    cv::Mat bufferImage;
    bool depthCaptured = false, colorCaptured = false;

    if(this->m_colorStreamStatus & this->m_depthStreamStatus)
    {
        while( !depthCaptured || !colorCaptured || m_depthTimeStamp != m_colorTimeStamp)
        {
            m_status = openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(m_streams, C_NUM_STREAMS, &m_currentStream, C_STREAM_TIMEOUT);
            if(m_status != openni::STATUS_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "OpenCVKinect: Unable to wait for streams. Exiting" << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            switch(m_currentStream)
            {
            case C_DEPTH_STREAM:
                m_depth.readFrame(&m_depthFrame);
                m_depthImage.create(m_depthFrame.getHeight(), m_depthFrame.getWidth(), CV_16UC1);
                m_depthImage.data = (uchar*)m_depthFrame.getData();
                this->m_depthTimeStamp = m_depthFrame.getTimestamp() >> 16;
                std::cout << "Depth Timestamp: " << this->m_depthTimeStamp << std::endl;
                depthCaptured = true;
                break;
            case C_COLOR_STREAM:
                m_color.readFrame(&m_colorFrame);
                m_colorImage.create(m_colorFrame.getHeight(), m_colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
                bufferImage.create(m_colorFrame.getHeight(), m_colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
                bufferImage.data = (uchar*)m_colorFrame.getData();
                this->m_colorTimeStamp = m_colorFrame.getTimestamp() >> 16;
                std::cout << "Color Timestamp: " << m_colorTimeStamp << std::endl;
                colorCaptured = true;
                cv::cvtColor(bufferImage, m_colorImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    else if(this->m_colorStreamStatus & !this->m_depthStreamStatus)
    {
        while(!colorCaptured)
        {
            m_status = openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(m_streams, C_NUM_STREAMS, &m_currentStream, C_STREAM_TIMEOUT);
            if(m_status != openni::STATUS_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "OpenCVKinect: Unable to wait for streams. Exiting" << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            switch(m_currentStream)
            {
            case C_COLOR_STREAM:
                m_color.readFrame(&m_colorFrame);
                m_colorImage.create(m_colorFrame.getHeight(), m_colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
                bufferImage.create(m_colorFrame.getHeight(), m_colorFrame.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);
                bufferImage.data = (uchar*)m_colorFrame.getData();
                this->m_colorTimeStamp = m_colorFrame.getTimestamp() >> 16;
                std::cout << "Color Timestamp: " << m_colorTimeStamp << std::endl;
                colorCaptured = true;
                cv::cvtColor(bufferImage, m_colorImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        m_depthImage = cv::Mat::zeros(m_colorImage.size(), CV_16UC1);
        /*returnVec.push_back(m_depthImage);
        returnVec.push_back(m_colorImage);
        bufferImage.release();*/
        return returnVec;

    }
    else if(!this->m_colorStreamStatus & this->m_depthStreamStatus)
    {
        while(!depthCaptured)
        {
            m_status = openni::OpenNI::waitForAnyStream(m_streams, C_NUM_STREAMS, &m_currentStream, C_STREAM_TIMEOUT);
            if(m_status != openni::STATUS_OK)
            {
                std::cout << "OpenCVKinect: Unable to wait for streams. Exiting" << std::endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            switch(m_currentStream)
            {
            case C_DEPTH_STREAM:
                m_depth.readFrame(&m_depthFrame);
                m_depthImage.create(m_depthFrame.getHeight(), m_depthFrame.getWidth(), CV_16UC1);
                m_depthImage.data = (uchar*)m_depthFrame.getData();
                this->m_depthTimeStamp = m_depthFrame.getTimestamp() >> 16;
                std::cout << "Depth Timestamp: " << this->m_depthTimeStamp << std::endl;
                depthCaptured = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        m_colorImage = cv::Mat::zeros(m_depthImage.size(), CV_8UC3);
        /*returnVec.push_back(m_depthImage);
        returnVec.push_back(m_colorImage);
        bufferImage.release();*/
        return returnVec;
    }
    else
    {

    m_colorImage = cv::Mat::zeros(10, 10, CV_8UC1);
    m_depthImage = cv::Mat::zeros(10, 10, CV_8UC1);

    /*returnVec.push_back(m_depthImage);
    returnVec.push_back(m_colorImage);
    bufferImage.release();
    return returnVec;*/
    }

    returnVec.push_back(m_depthImage); //ERROR
    returnVec.push_back(m_colorImage);
    bufferImage.release();
    return returnVec;
}
```

And this is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    displayIntroAndUsage();
    cv::vector<cv::Mat> dataStream;
    OpenCVKinect myDataCap;

    int selectedOption = 0;
    DISPLAY_OPTIONS:
    displayMenu();

    std::cin >> selectedOption;
    switch(selectedOption)
    {
    case 1:
        myDataCap.setMode(C_MODE_COLOR);
        break;
    case 2:
        myDataCap.setMode(C_MODE_DEPTH);
        break;
    case 3:
        myDataCap.setMode(C_MODE_DEPTH | C_MODE_COLOR);
        break;
    case 4:
        myDataCap.setMode(C_MODE_DEPTH | C_MODE_COLOR | C_MODE_ALIGNED);
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Error: Invalid option selected." << std::endl;
        goto DISPLAY_OPTIONS;
        break;
    }

    if(!myDataCap.init())
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char ch = ' ';
    while(ch != 27)
    {
        dataStream = myDataCap.getData();
        std::cout << dataStream.size() <<  std::endl;
        dataStream[0];
        cv::imshow("Depth", dataStream[C_DEPTH_STREAM]);
        cv::imshow("Color", dataStream[C_COLOR_STREAM]);
        ch = cv::waitKey(10);
    }
    return 1;
}
```